# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'draggable'. (Booklet jquery plugin)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use Booklet jquery plugin for my project, but the manual and keyboard controls are not working. It seems to be due to this error.

[Booklet plugin homepage](http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/)

[Direct link to the js file of the plugin. Error occurs at line 1194.](http://pastebay.net/1071123)

The error occurs at this particular line :

```
    // manual page turning, check if jQuery UI is loaded
    target.find('.b-page').draggable('destroy').removeClass('b-grab b-grabbing');
    if(options.manual && $.ui) {
```

My html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
            <title> asfds </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="fgerg.css" />
<link href="scripts/jquery.booklet.1.4.0.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.booklet.1.4.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {

                $(function() {
                    $('#mybook').booklet(); 
                    keyboard: true
                });     
                }); 
            </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="mybook">
        <div> 
            <h3>Yay, Page 1!</h3>
        </div>
        <div> 
            <img src="scripts/testmenu1.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </div>
        <div> 
            <h3>Yay, Page 3!</h3>
        </div>
        <div> 
            <h3>Yay, Page 4!</h3>
        </div>
        <div> 
            <h3>Yay, Page 5!</h3>
        </div>
        <div> 
            <h3>Yay, Page 6!</h3>
        </div>
</body>     
    </div>

    </html>
```

Comment: What OS and browser? Seems fine on Safari/Mac OS X

Comment: FF and Chrome. It works fine on the plugin's site, but when I copy the exact code and implement it in my project page, the error occurs.

Comment: Did you read the section *Installation*?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think draggable comes from [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/), so you will probably need to include it as well.

Comment: mind that if you don't have the full library, the draggable feature may be missing. Do remember to tick the checkbox in front of "Draggable" when downloading the library http://jqueryui.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function() {
                $('#mybook').booklet( {keyboard: true} ); 

            });
```

put the "keyboard: true" inside booklet( ) function to get the options